# How to make a C++ templated function agnostic to the return type for future specialization

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++11

I would like to have a general templated function declaration for which I do not know (already) the return type, similar to:

```
**template <class T> auto getIds() noexcept -> std::vector<Any>;**
```

The function could then be specialized with several input types, and a return type based on it:

```
template <> auto getIds<MyClass>() noexcept -> std::vector<decltype(MyClass::id)>
{
    // implementation here.
}
```

And finally call it without to set the return:

```
auto val = getIds<MyClass>();
```

Is that possible? How?

**Notes:**

What I want to avoid is to have to set manually the Id type in the call function:

```
auto val = getIds<MyClass, decltype(MyClass::id)>(); // Ugly
```

I also discard any (non based on template) solution like extending all types from a RootMyClass. Is not that these solutions are bad, but they miss the point of this question.

**Trying to be a bit clearer:**

If I wrote

```
class MyClass { public: int id1=4;};
template <class T, class Id> auto getIds() -> Id;
template <> auto getIds<MyClass, decltype(MyClass::id1)>() -> decltype(MyClass::id1)
{
    return 1;
}

auto main() -> int
{
    getIds<MyClass>(); // Do not compile
    getIds<MyClass, decltype(MyClass::id1)>(); // Compile but ugly
}
```

I would like the return type to be implicit, but I did not found a way to achieve that with specializations:

```
template <class T> getIds() noexcept -> WHICH TYPE?;
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Are you just looking for how to explicitly specialize function templates for different return types?

Comment: No, I am asking how to declare a function template when the return is not already known (will be known in the specialization).

Comment: Why ordinary function specialization does not work for you? It already allows you to have different return types.

Comment: well, the std::vector<ANY> is not allowed.

Comment: If you don't have a default implementation, you can mark it as returning void. Noone is going to call it anyway.

Comment: `template <class T> getIds() noexcept -> decltype(T::id)`?

Comment: Do you want the return type to be MyClass::id usually (always)?  You can try a second parameter with default argument, `template<class MyClass, class Id = MyClass::id> Id getIds();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change the return type in a specialization, unfortunately. What you can do is change the return type in different overloads. Obviously. Furthermore, function template specializations are much more complicated than function overloads anyway, so let's do that.

Introduce an empty type wrapper, say:

```
template <typename T> struct wrapper { };
```

And forward the default implementation to that (I'm assuming C++14 here, otherwise you could wrap that in `decltype()` with a trailing return):

```
template <typename T>
auto getIds() { return getIds(wrapper<T>{}); }
```

Declare the generic version as:

```
template <typename T>
void getIds(wrapper<T> );
```

Don't define it. Then, anytime somebody tries to do:

```
auto ids = getIds<X>();
```

If there is no overload, that will simply fail to compile as you cannot assign from `void`. Then, you can overload as you see fit:

```
std::vector<decltype(MyClass::id)> getIds(wrapper<MyClass> )
{ ... }
```

**FINAL EXAMPLE:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T> struct wrapper { };

template <typename T>
auto getIds() -> decltype(getIds(wrapper<T>{}))
{
    return getIds(wrapper<T>{});
}

template <typename T>
void getIds(wrapper<T> ) { }

struct MyClass {
    int id;
};

std::vector<decltype(MyClass::id)> getIds(wrapper<MyClass> )
{
    return {1, 2, 3};
}

int main()
{
    for (auto id : getIds<MyClass>()) {
        std::cout << id << " ";
    }

}
```

Comment: [Specialization can't change the return type.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ce6f8f8ac40b927)

Comment: @T.C. Completely forgot about that. Rewrote most of the answer.

Comment: I am trying to make a simple test with your answer. I have to admit that I do not understand fully the concept with the wrapper type.
What is the trailing return for the first getIds function?
Could you add please a simple example that compile in C++11?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually *very* similar to Haskell typeclasses, and, surprisingly, works. For real usage I would use functors to allow partial specializations, though.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> 
decltype(T::x) getX(T const& t) { return; }

class A { public: int x; A(int x):x(x){} };
template<> int getX<A>(A const& a) {
    return a.x;
}

class B { public: std::string x; B(std::string x):x(std::move(x)){}  };
template<> std::string getX<B>(B const& b) {
    return b.x;
}

int main() {
    A a(42);
    B b("43");

    std::cout << getX(a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << getX(b) << std::endl;
}
```

As you can see, each specialization has to (can?) provide the return type explicitly. `decltype(A::x)` (and `B::x)`, respectively) could be used instead if you so prefer.

---

To make it even more Haskell-ish, you could expect a type tag in the type itself (basically a type family):

```
template<typename T> 
typename T::TypeOfX getX(T const& t) { return; }
```

And consequently:

```
class A {
    using TypeOfX = int;
    TypeOfX someComplexLogicToGetX();
};
```

Both solutions to the type being instantiated for the actual type, except one gets it from a type of a field, and the other from a direct "type variable".

Comment: It do not compile with VS2013 :-S 
C2912: explicit specialization 'int getX<A>(const A &)' is not a specialization of a function template

Comment: @AdrianMaire Funny, because [G++ likes it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c70394bafc5fea44). I wonder who's right here, but Clang accepting it as well makes me think that it's just another VS compiler problem.

Comment: Could be, I do not like VS2013 either, but I am not who decide that here.

Comment: @AdrianMaire you could try the 2nd version I suppose.

Comment: VS2013 seem to don't like it neither: same error. It is like the return value is part of the signature.